# Does there exists soutions to this system of trigonometric equations?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

For two given integers $k,l\in\mathbb{N}$ and any real values $A,B,C,D$ satisfying $A^2+B^2+C^2+D^2=1$, does the following system of equations has a solution, on $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$?

- $\cos(kx)\cos(ly)=A$
- $\cos(kx)\sin(ly)=B$
- $\sin(kx)\cos(ly)=C$
- $\sin(kx)\sin(ly)=D$

I think that in general the answer is no, but in that case, what extra conditions do I need to ask $A,B,C,D$ to have a solution? Thanks!

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Comment: Hint: Consider the computation $$\cos^2(kx + ly) + \sin^2(kx + ly).$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, generally, the system does not have a solution.

Let me assume that $k = l = 1$. (If $k = 0$ or $l = 0$, this leads to a degenerate case of your system which you can study apart easily. If $k > 1$ or $l> 1$, you can simply rescale the unknowns and look for $x' = kx$ and $y' = ly$.)

So you are trying to solve
$$
\begin{cases}
\cos x \cos y = A, \\
\cos x \sin y = B, \\
\sin x \cos y = C, \\
\sin x \sin y = D.
\end{cases}
$$
You can start by solving for $x$. You get $\cos^2 x = A^2+B^2$ and $\sin^2 x = C^2+D^2$. Thanks to you hypothesis, you can find such an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (in fact, there are many solutions).

Then you can solve for $y$ using the first two lines or the last two lines. Here, you indeed have two many constraints. Since $\cos^2 y$ must be the same whether you compute it using the first two lines or the last two ones, this imposes $A^2/(A^2+B^2) = C^2/(C^2+D^2)$. Also, for the signs to agree, you must have $ABCD > 0$.

Under these two additional assumptions (which are anyway necessary), I believe your system has a solution (in fact, many).